# Spring MVC search box intellisense

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hey I want to retrieve the list of usernames from the controller when I click on the text box(search box) from my view page and display it. 
This is my code in JSP

```
<div id="nae_menu" style="display: none">
    <div class="chromestyle" id="nae_chromemenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a target="content_frame" href="/omp/order"      rel="nae_submenu_orders">Orders</a></li>
            <li><a target="content_frame" href="/omp/trial/list" rel="nae_submenu_trials">Trial Requests</a></li>
            <li><a target="content_frame" href="/omp/audits">Audit Logs</a></li>
            <li><form method="get"   action="customer">
                 <input type="text" value="default" /> <input type="submit" value="search"/> search
                 </form> 
                 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is my controller where I am stuck.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderManagementController.class);
@Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{customerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView ViewAllOrdersForCustomer(@PathVariable long customerId,
        ModelMap model,
        HttpSession httpSession)
{
    List<Order> orders = orderService.getAllOrdersForCustomer(customerId);

    model.addAttribute("customerId", customerId);
    model.addAttribute("orders", orders);

    return new ModelAndView("order/list");
}
```

help me to make this work and please help me to add intellisense to this as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors and or getting any undesired output ? please elaborate your current position

Comment: I am facing problems in relating the search tag with the controller and i am not able to retrieve any username.

Comment: consider using a JSP form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a ways to go in terms of understanding what the problem actually is.  Think of this problem in terms of smaller parts:

- Figure out a means to transfer a list of usernames from the
  controller to the view.  In this case, it sounds like you want to use
  ajax since you want something to happen when a user performs a click.
- If you do in fact want to use ajax, figure out how spring WebMVC
  supports it (it does -- I suggest looking in to MappingJackson /
  Spring integration).  You'll basically need to include the
  appropriate dependencies, and then in your controller add a method
  such as

  @RequestMapping("/fetchUsernames")
  public @ResponseBody List fetchUsernames() {
             ...
  }
- you'll need to call this ajax method from the client.  You could use JQuery's `$.ajax(...)` method to do this, or there are a bunch of
  other frameworks that support it.
- you'll then need to take the results of this call and populate some piece of the UI (a select box, an auto-complete box, ???)  I'm not
  sure what exactly you want to do.

But that's the idea behind it.  Good luck.